# Callcode | Delegatecall don't work

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, delegatecall, callcode

I was playing around with `call`, `delegatecall` and `callcode` and discovered that the function `reset` stopped working after I had made a callcode call (here are my actions):

FROM JS SIDE:

```
— A.makeCall({gas:300000}); // NO ERRORS
— A.sender(); // 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 AS EXPECTED
— A.myVar(); // 0 AS EXPECTED
— B.sender(); // addressA AS EXPECTED
— B.myVar(); // 1 AS EXPECTED

— A.reset({gas: 300000}); // NO ERRORS;

— A.sender(); // 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 AS EXPECTED
— A.myVar(); // 0 AS EXPECTED
— B.sender(); // 0x0 AS EXPECTED
— B.myVar(); // 0 AS EXPECTED

— A.makeCallCode({gas:300000}); // NO ERRORS
— A.sender(); // 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002 Oops! It looks like there was no access to msg.sender and sender variable was assigned argument x instead. 
— A.myVar(); // 0 Oops! Nothing was assigned, because of the ↑
— B.sender(); // 0x0 AS EXPECTED
— B.myVar(); // 0 AS EXPECTED

— A.reset({gas: 300000}); //ALL KIND OF ERRORS; WTF IS GOING ON HERE? NO MATTER HOW MUCH GAS I SUPPLY IT STILL FAILS. https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x6654b6739f55690c7114fa9e8cfb7a5959e73d60c37782aee4e211487de859f2
```

---

```
contract A {
    address public addressB;   
    address public sender;
    uint public myVar;

    function A() {
        addressB = new B();
    }

    function makeCall(){
        addressB.call(bytes4(sha3('set(uint256)')), 1);
    }
    function makeCallCode(){
        addressB.callcode(bytes4(sha3('set(uint256)')), 2);
    }
    function makeDelegateCall(){
        addressB.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3('set(uint256)')), 3);
    }

    function reset(){
        sender = 0;
        myVar = 0;
        B(addressB).reset();
    }
}

contract B {
    address public sender;
    uint public myVar;

    function set(uint x){
        myVar = x;
        sender = msg.sender;
    }
    function reset(){
        sender = 0;
        myVar = 0;        
    }
}
```

Comment: please make a title that's relevant to the problem.  e.g.  "reset not working after making a callcode call - Solidity bug?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has to do with how variables arranged in the storage. The storage of the called and the calling contract should match. 
The answer to this question can be found here https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/944